# localStorage not working or am I mistaking?

Tags: jquery, local-storage

On page reload.php I have the following code:

```
<head>
   <script>
   localStorage.setItem("bar", "hoi");
   </script>
</head>
```

On page home.php I have:

```
<head>
   <script>
   var lastid = localStorage.getItem("bar");
   </script>
</head>
```

Isn't this correct? Can't i storage on one page and get it on another page?

When i put the storage and the get on the same page it works..

Comment: It should work, if the pages are under same domain. You can check it under `Resources` tab of the developer tolls if you use chrome.

Comment: Remember, www.example.com and example.com are two different domains - this could explain your issue.

Comment: It is in the same ftp folder, or isn't this what you guys mean?

Comment: If you navigate to `www.example.com/reload.php`, and then to `example.com/home.php`, for example, local storage will **not** work right because the domains are different. That is what I mean by my first comment. Please confirm this is not your issue.

Comment: to get the localStorage you can also try this

"var lastid= localStorage.bar;"

Comment: Is it necessary to navigate to each other? Can't they work along each other? It's about a very complex case. Let's say the code I wrote in the question is just all the code I have? That's the reason it won't work?

Comment: From your example above, and the fact that this code works when it's on the same page, and baring that LS is not disabled somehow when the page changes, then this is one explanation.

Comment: @norcode got me the right answer, it fix the problem! Can u please put your comment in an answer?

Answer (score 0):

> Can't I [use local storage] on one page and get it on another page?

Yes, you absolutely can.

> When I put the storage and the get it on the same page it works.

This might be an issue with subtly different domains. If you navigate to `www.example.com/reload.php`, and then to `example.com/home.php`, for example, `bar` will not be retrieved from local storage because the two pages are different domains.

If you are using any AJAX scripts, or hard urls, please confirm that both the pages are run from the same domain.

---

Also, you can access local storage in a few ways:

```
var lastid = localStorage.getItem("bar");
var lastid = localStorage["bar"];
var lastid = localStorage.bar;
```